# Selenium Web driver automation framework with Edge driver

Tags: web, selenium-webdriver, driver, microsoft-edge

I meet some serious issue when I try to run my automation selenium java framework with Edge web driver. the browser is opened but nothing more. I use right Edge driver version for my currently installed Edge browser but everything stops after the opening of the browser . The framework is running correctly with gecko and chrome drivers. Did you have some related issues with Edge driver capability ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Edge browser is automatically updated, and now you need the latest webdriver [version](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Answer (score 0):

seems that I found the problem. it was related with Xpath locator in my cases. The Microsoft driver still not support searching by xpath locator.